# How to remove files starting with #! or ending with .sh in the name

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to shell programming.  I want to move any executable file, any file starting with shebang(#!), and any file whose name ends with `.sh` from a directory to /tmp/backup and log the names of the files moved.

This is what I have done till now

Searching for files with `#^`

```
grep -ircl --exclude=*.{png,jpg,gif,html,jar} "^#" /home
```

Finding  executables

```
find . -type f -perm +111 or find . -type f -perm -u+x
```

Now I am struggling how to club these two commands get a final output which I can pass to perform backup and remove from current directory

Thanks

Comment: The best way to learn is to try it first then ask for guidance when you're stuck. If you have already attempted this, do post what you've done so far so others can give you specific and relevant advice.

Comment: This is what I have done till now 
Seraching for files with #^
 
grep -ircl --exclude=*.{png,jpg,gif,html,jar} "^#" /home
 
Finding  executables 
find . -type f -perm +111 or find . -type f -perm -u+x
 
Now I am struggling how to club these two commands get a final output which I can pass to perform backup and remove from current directory

Comment: Do edit that into your question. It is difficult to read code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use the xargs command

"find command" | xargs "grep command"

Answer (score 0):

You could put everything in a file, sort it, then process it with Awk:

```
# Select all files to move
grep -ircl --exclude=*.{png,jpg,gif,html,jar} '^#\!' /home > list.txt
find /home -type f \( -perm -u+x -o -name "*.sh" \) -print >> list.txt

# Feed them to Awk that will log and move the file
sort list.txt | uniq | awk -v LOGFILE="mylog.txt" '

{ print "Moving " $0 >> LOGFILE
  "mv -v --backup \"" $0 "\" /tmp/backup" | getline
  print >> LOGFILE }'
```

EDIT: you can make a formal script out of this skeleton, by adding some variables and some additional checks:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST="$( mktemp || exit 1 )"
LOG="/tmp/mylog.txt"
SOURCE="/home"
TARGET="/tmp/backup"

mkdir -p "${TARGET}"

cd "${SOURCE}" || exit 1

# Select all files to move
grep -ircl --exclude=*.{png,jpg,gif,html,jar} '^#\!' "${SOURCE}" > "${LIST}"
find "${SOURCE}" -type f \( -perm -u+x -o -name "*.sh" \) -print >> "${LIST}"

# Feed them to Awk that will log and move the file
sort "${LIST}" | uniq | awk -v LOGFILE="${LOG}" -v TARGET="${TARGET}" '

{ print "Moving " $0 >> LOGFILE
  "mv -v --backup \"" $0 "\" " TARGET | getline
  print >> LOGFILE }'
```

Comment: Hi, Its giving me following error.                                                sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Could you please provide little brief about script working also?

Comment: The commands should work without change. Maybe you forgot a double-quote or a backslash somewhere (it might in the quoting in the awk command). I have added an example of a more formal script out of the commands I have given. HTH.

Comment: I tested both the commands and the full script and they worked correctly for me.